# Как разбить папки с цифровыми именами в иерархию?

Tags: структуры-данных, nosql

Данные хранятся в файлах в папках с цифровыми именами, соотв. id объектов. Диапазон чисел от 1 до 3e9. Ещё и со знаком. Сейчас отрицательные и положительные живут отдельно: `plus/1234455/` и `minus/123456`.

Операции сводятся к тому, что есть `id`, и надо определить, в какой папке лежат его файлы (и на каком сервере, в случае шардинга).

**Хочется** равномерно разбить их в иерархическую структуру 1-2-3 уровней вложенности, чтобы уменьшить число объектов в одной папке, и с прицелом на как-бы-шардинг.

Стоит ли делать это просто по первым цифрам, или есть более удачный подход?

```
12/        -> 1/2/
123/       -> 1/2/3/
123456789/ -> 1/2/3456789/
```

Так получается, что «короткие» папки будут содержать как собственные данные, так и подпапки. Некруто.

Кто знаком с изнанкой всяких MongoDB – как там похожая задача решается?

Answer (score 1):

Собственно для файлов с короткими именами можно сделать отдельный каталог,
чтобы они лежали не вместе с подкаталогами длинных имён.
Например:

```
  1  ->  1/_/
  12 ->  1/2/_/
  123 -> 1/2/3/
```

Или же можно просто дополнить числа нулями слева до длины максимального числа,
в этом случае все имена будут одинаковой длины:

```
   001 -> 0/0/1/
   012 -> 0/1/2/
   123 -> 1/2/3/
```

Другой, более важный, вопрос, является ли распределение номеров действительно равномерным и не получится ли так, что большинство имён будет начинаться с какой-то определённой цифры, например, с 1.

В этом случае нужно проводить хэширование имени, которое сделает распределение действительно равномерным.

Если есть высокие требования, то стоит использовать производительные хэши,
такие как xxhash, например. Он не является криптографическим, но в данном случае это и не нужно.

Скорость различных алгоритмов/реализаций хэширования (64-битные варианты ещё значительно быстрее):

```
Name            Speed       Q.Score   Author
xxHash          5.4 GB/s     10
MumurHash 3a    2.7 GB/s     10       Austin Appleby
SpookyHash      2.0 GB/s     10       Bob Jenkins
SBox            1.4 GB/s      9       Bret Mulvey
Lookup3         1.2 GB/s      9       Bob Jenkins
CityHash64      1.05 GB/s    10       Pike & Alakuijala
FNV             0.55 GB/s     5       Fowler, Noll, Vo
CRC32           0.43 GB/s     9
MD5-32          0.33 GB/s    10       Ronald L. Rivest
SHA1-32         0.28 GB/s    10
```

В том случае, если вероятность, что в будущем нужно будет менять распределение имен между узлами (каталогами) или распределение должно быть не равномерно, а на какие-то узлы должно приходиться большее количество имен,
можно рассмотреть использование *консистентного хэширования* (consistent hashing). Оно используется в Cassandra, в Riak, и много ещё где.

- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Consistent_hashing (англ.)

Comment: с хэшами рискую попасть на коллизии. ID в пределе могут заполнить полностью весь диапазон от 1 до 1e10, и тогда с большинством алгоритмов коллиизии неизбежны.

Наверное, надо просто бить на равные диапазоны, напр. 1..1e4, 10001..2e4 и т.п.

Comment: @Sergiks: Ну и что, что коллизии? Будет несколько подкаталогов в одном. Что тут такого?

Comment: Если числа равномерно распределены, то можно бить, конечно же, просто нарезать по, скажем, 3 цифры в имени и всё, но если числа распределены не равномерно, то нужно обязательно хэщирование

Comment: Кажется, сообразил: нужен не хэш, а [биекция](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%91%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F) – скажем, реверс битов – для относительно равномерного заполнения 32-битного пространства имён, без коллизий. И после этого уже можно по первым символам (добитым нулями до восьми 16-ричных позиций) бить на папки.

Comment: Да, если номера действительно равномерно распределены, то да. Я там писал в ответе, что можно просто нулями спереди добавить и порезать просто на группы цифр (грубо говоря по три).

Answer (score 0):

В итоге сделал через реверс порядка битов для равномерности распределения на первых уровнях, и бью по парам 16-ричных цифр.

Напр. `12345` при изменении порядка 32 битов на зеркальный, становится `9C0C0000`, которые в моём случае бьются на три группы по 2, 2 и 4 символа, образуя путь `9C/0C/0000`.